# How do you retrieve set values without removing the values, and randomly inputting them into a dictionary?

Tags: python, set

It's a lot. However, we are trying to make a code in which the user picks from three options, where each one has different prizes. We have to use a set = '', '', '' (strings) and the dictionary = {1: value, 2: value, 3: value}.  WE have to randomize the set strings to the values in the dictionary every time so the user can continuously get a different prize regardless of the number they choose.

Since they are sets, we can't index them. Using basic coding from python or a method, what is a good way to retrieve, and randomize these strings to a different dictionary value?

```
print("[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] \n")


Prizes = set("Oculus X", "N/A", "Money")


gift_box = {1: Prizes, 2: Prizes, 3: Prizes}

# Will let user choose
user_input = int(input("> Choose a Gift Box to open: "))
```

Comment: Use a list instead of a set.

Comment: Create a list from the set. Use `random` module to shuffle the list, then create a dict from the list

Comment: Also, `set("Oculus X", "N/A", "Money")` would raise a `TypeError`....